# Should students get another chance at a math question because of English troubles?

Tags: secondary-education, testing

The question is John has locked a 4 digit combination lock with each of the numbers 0-9. He knows the numbers 1,4,6, appears exactly once, but he does not remember the position of the numbers and he is not sure of what the fourth number is.

The student think the fourth number is the number in the fourth position of the combination lock. He thinks so because people do not say an order of the number you know or not know. So later I wanted him to try again with the right idea. There are two students who thought this way. The students first language is not English.  I would let them try again since its not a math issue and would you? Also can it also be interpreted this way?

Comment: If the question is worded exactly as you've given it (has several ambiguities, some grammar errors, etc.), I would be very generous with complaints by students. Teachers should have sufficient command of the subject matter and writing questions to anticipate (and thus avoid) these type of issues when writing questions. For example, since the combinations are "4 digit numbers", it is reasonable to assume $0$ cannot be the left-most digit, but then you say "each of the numbers 0-9", which suggests otherwise.

Comment: FYI, the following is less ambiguous: *The correct combination to John’s lock consists of* $4$ *digits in a certain order and each chosen from* $0$ *through* $9,$ *any or all of which can be repeated. John does not completely remember the correct combination, but he does know that each of the digits* $1,$ $4,$ *and* $6$ *appears exactly once.* The answer to the presumed question that follows is $(4)(3!)(7),$ as there are $4$ locations to put the three known digits, $3!$ ways to permute the three known digits, and $7$ possibilities for choosing the remaining digit (whose location is now fixed).

Comment: So the student's concern could be justified?

Comment: Yes, I think it is justified. If you are writing the questions, and you find it difficult to avoid issues like this (and they will be difficult until you get more  question writing practice and teaching experience), my advice would be to include some examples, which in this case could be $0416$ and $0461$ and $6184$ as consistent with what John knows, and $4116$ and $2356$ as inconsistent with what John knows. (This many examples might be overkill, however.)

Comment: Ok Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @SelwynLiu Another strategy is to ask a colleague to look over your questions before you present them to students, or to only ask questions which you obtain from a reliable external source.

Comment: *any or all of which can be repeated* --- In looking at this 7 hours later, I see that there is a slight ambiguity even in what I wrote: Does "repeated" mean exactly two occurrences or two or more occurrences? I suppose one could write "any or all of which can be repeated one or more times", but now the verbiage might start playing a nontrivial role in solving the item (especially for [ESL students](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_second_or_foreign_language)). However, this particular ambiguity doesn't arise if the student understands the other constraints.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, so can it be interpreted in the student's way?

Comment: Yes, it can be interpreted in the student's way. You wrote "*but he does not remember the position of the numbers and he is not sure of what the fourth number is*". The word "position" occurs in this sentence, followed by "fourth", so a reasonable interpretation is that "fourth" refers to the position of the number, and not the remaining number. There are two orders, the order of the digits in the combination lock and the order you used when speaking about the digits. If someone isn't sure which order you meant, then isn't it reasonable to assume you meant the most recently mentioned order?

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Does such order even exist of 1,4,6? it feels like the order is not relevant. They are just numbers.

Comment: By writing "fourth number" shortly after the list 1, 4, 6 you introduce the possibility of an unintended reading of your words. This could have been avoided by using "remaining number" or some other phrase that doesn't have an order connotation. When I write something in which I'm especially worried about misinterpretation (and this is the case for ANY problem on a student test), I try to imagine all the ways a malicious nit-picking student could find fault with what I've written when arguing for extra points because of some oversight I made in writing the problem.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I thought the order of that 1,4,6 being mentioned is not relveant of my question, as just think of them as numbers, is that tight? Also does the interpretation of unknown complete the understanding of the sequence of the 4 numbers so this interpretation becomes better

Comment: The issue is not what you thought or what you intended, but how what you have written could be reasonably misinterpreted (whether intentional or unintentional) by someone else, and I've already dealt with this fairly extensively. To make this more general, the kinds of things you need to be on the lookout for are things like [structural ambiguities](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22structural+ambiguity%22) and [scope ambiguities](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scope+ambiguity%22). **(continued)**

Comment: Unless you've lived in a cave all your life, surely you've encountered things like this in your life experiences --- trouble-making students who are extremely literal-minded and wise cracking students (those you've taught and/or the various things your classmates said to teachers when you were a student), jokes people make that employ double meanings, reading/hearing about court cases that involve subtle linguistic wording issues, etc. What you want to do is anticipate some of the ways that students like this could misinterpret (either intentionally or unintentionally) what you've written.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I agree with your idea but why some other people do not think it can be interpreted that way?

Comment: Not everyone is equally cognizant of other people's possible interpretations. Also, I've done this for a living for 15 years (edit the wording of problems in various international math tests and train others to do so), so I suspect I have a bit more experience in this than most people.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thanks, I am just not sure of the universal answer, but some people just probably do not see it.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro  Someone said this: what do u think？ There is no reference anywhere to a number in the fourth position. I accept that in some language which isn't my native English "but not the fourth" might mean "the fourth position".

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at, but if you are saying someone is trying to argue with you that there isn't an ambiguity, then they're missing the point. This is not a black and white issue, but one in which the presence of some grayness (when recognized) is sufficient reason to clarify the wording, UNLESS specific issues of English grammar and usage are being tested. I've given several specific arguments why this has some grayness (e.g. comment beginning with "By writing "fourth number" shortly after the list 1, 4, 6"), **(continued)**

Comment: and simply saying "there is no reference anywhere to a number in the fourth position" does not address them. Indeed, I could ask why having or not having such a reference is relevant. For example, not having an explicit reference to number doesn't prevent the possibility of there being a "between the lines" reference to number. In my arguments I think I was pretty careful about providing an explanation for the things I brought up that go beyond some apparent rule pulled out of a hat.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thank you

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I also list a few examples along with such combinatorics problem descriptions.  In this problem I might say that 1476, 4216, 1614 (even though the digit 1 appears twice) are all possible combinations, since they all use the digits 1, 4, and 6 at least once.  However, 1234 is not a valid combination since 6 was not included in any position.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro  someone also said this: We have 3 digits (1,4,6) explicitly identified, and the only reference to positions (first,second,...) is "fourth". It's simply implausible that a speaker would choose to use that unqualified ordinal to mean fourth position rather than the contextually implied fourth [remaining unknown] digit.

Comment: "that a speaker would choose" --- Tell the person we're not interested in what the speaker chooses or means, but rather what a listener/reader might interpret or understand. If the question is not important, it's probably fine -- tell students what it means if they bring up the issue. If the question is part of a very significant or important test, then it's not fine for many reasons. Note how I rephrased the question earlier. It might be helpful to think carefully about each word and phrase choice I made, especially when it differs from the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an English language issue, but a poorly worded question.  Even for a native speaker, the question is ambiguous/confusing.

I would have thought you meant fourth position, also.  Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems like you are asking for very legalistic grammatical precision if I am wrong.  Nothing like normal English comprehension.  (And I'm not even sure I am wrong.)

Comment: You are indicating the fourth number in the sequence of the combination lock?

Comment: Yes.  Like fourth from the left.

Comment: why did u think this way that 4th positon of combiantion lock？

Comment: I don't know why I think that way.

Comment: Do u think is irrational to think it is the fourth position than the 4th number of 1,4,6?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Do u think it can mean 4th number of 1,4,6?

Comment: Not trying to be a grammar nit, but your English is generally hard to follow.